# Why does retrofit want me to use Query

Tags: android, retrofit2, okhttp

I am getting the following error:
Caused by:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: URL query string "c={category}" must not have replace block. For dynamic query parameters use @Query.
```

I have tried to following the documentation for dynamic questions and this seems to be the way to do it.

I have also tried using the @Query tag but with no luck.

This is my request:

```
@GET("filter.php?c={category}")
fun getRecipesForCategory(@Path("category") categoryName: String): Single<Meals>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have to use `@Query` keyword to add query to a request

```
@GET("filter.php")
fun getRecipesForCategory( @Query("c") String queryParameter): Single<Meals>
```

this will be translated to

> `www.yourBaseURl.com/filter.php?c=queryParameter`

Comment: Then what gets passed in to the queryParameter variable?\

Comment: You pass what you are querying for

Comment: I then get IllegalArgumentException: URL "filter.php" does not contain "{category}". (parameter #1)